# Вывести второе простое число из диапазона от 50 до 70 с помощью for и if

Tags: java, простые-числа

```
boolean b = true;
        for (int P = 50; P <= 70; P++) {
            for (int i = 2; i < P; i++) {
                if (P % i == 0) {
                    b = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        if (b) System.out.println(P);
        else b = true;
        }
```

Comment: И...? Задайте вопрос.

Comment: @MBo, Этот код выводит все простые числа диапазона, а нужно только второе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 boolean second = false;
 ...

   if (b) {
      if (second) {
        System.out.println(P);
        break;
       }
     second = true;  
 }
```

Comment: Не понял, тупой наверное, а как second привязан к выводу чисел?

Comment: первое простое не выводится, second становится true. второе выводится, внешний цикл останавливается. И boolean b = true; нужно внутрь цикла ввести, после первого for

Comment: thanks a lot!.........